# How to share Authentication settings?

Tags: paw-app

I have several requests that use the same oAuth2 login. Can I easily share these settings for a group of requests?

In Postman I can create a collection, define an authentication method for this group and use this authentication for all requests in this collection.

Is there anything like this in Paw?

I can't believe I need to reenter the whole oAuth2 Parameters on each new request.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer here? Seems like a kind of baseline functionality.